# I know that any two left/right cosets are either equal or disjoint, but what about the sets of cosets?

Tags: group-theory

I know that the set of left cosets $G/H$ and the set of right cosets $H\backslash G$ contain elements (cosets) which are either equal or disjoint between themselves. Can the same be said for these two sets? If $H \trianglelefteq G$, I know that they are equal. If $H \ntrianglelefteq G$, are they disjoint?

Comment: Don't both contain H, in particular? So how can they be disjoint?

Comment: If the question makes any sense, it's asking about the non-identity cosets...

Comment: @GTonyJacobs - No, if the question were to make any sense, in the direction you suggest, it should ask "what is the intersection" (that is, which left cosets are also right cosets). That would lead to a meaningful concept in group theory - the *normalizer* of $H$. I doubt that the OP meant that, though.

Comment: Ok , I'm sure your interpretation is right...

Comment: @mathguy How will the intersection lead towards normalizer?

Comment: I think there is some confusion between the intersection of the *set of* left cosets with the *set of* right cosets, as opposed to intersections of particular left cosets with particular right cosets.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs  -  there should be no confusion, I explained exactly what I meant in parentheses in my Comment.

Comment: @shrinit - Which left cosets are also right cosets? The normalizer of $H$ is **by definition** the set of elements for which the left coset with respect to $H$ is equal to the right coset.

Comment: @mathguy, why are you being defensive? I didn't say you were confused, nor that your explanation wasn't good.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs - no, I thought you were suggesting that shrinit was confused about what I meant. And I explained he shouldn't have been, since I explained what I meant. Also the OP specifically talked about the sets of cosets (not individual left/right cosets) - although we don't know if the OP meant what he said.

Comment: Well..... *I* was confused between the two interpretations, whether or not I *should* have been.

Comment: @mathguy yeah true, you are making the largest subgroup of G (normalizer of H) where H is normal. I was confused about the intersection part. Thank  you mathguy

Comment: @mathguy Is the normaliser related to the stabiliser or centraliser of the group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $S_3$, take $H = \langle (1 2) \rangle $ and take left and right coset each H by (123). You can see they are not equal. In fact, if H is not normal in G then they are neither equal nor disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but I think it's this:

Suppose $H$ is not normal in $G$, and let $aH$ and $Hb$ be a left- and right-coset, respectively. Is it true that we have either $aH=Hb$ or else $aH\cap Hb=\emptyset$?

The answer to this question is no. You can see this by simply writing out the left and right cosets of a non-normal subset in some group. The smallest group in which you can do this is $S_3$, using the subgroup generated by any order $2$ element.

Comment: Thank you for that, I thought it was the case! I was actually asking whether 
 it must be that either $\{gH : g \in G\} = \{Hg : g \in G\}$ (in this case $H\trianglelefteq G$) or $\{gH : g \in G\}  \cap  \{Hg : g \in G\} = \varnothing$.  @shrinit's answer shows that this it is not true.

Comment: For a fixed $g$, it's clear that $g\in gH$ as well as $g\in Hg$, so the intersection of particular left-and right cosets by the same element can't be empty. Letting $g$ vary, and looking at collections of cosets, consider that we could have $g=e$. In that case, $eH$ and $He$ are certainly the same set.